# Авторизация VK в связке с Firebase

Tags: android, вконтакте, firebase

Необходимо реализовать авторизацию в андроид приложении через VK в связке через Firebase без использования собственного сервера.

Поиск советует сделать через https://auth0.com/ сервис, но непонятно каким образом? Кто-нибудь реализовывал данную схему, как?

Comment: Подскажите, есть ли решение?

Answer (score 8):

> **UPD**: код, указанный ниже, был использован с **VK SDK ~1.6.7**. Код с использованием текущей версии **SDK(2.0.0+)** может во многом отличаться от приведенного в примере - в частности, потому, что класс `VKAccessToken` был переписан и поля `email` теперь предположительно нет в открытом доступе. Однако решение есть: https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk/issues/399

В виду того, что прошло достаточно много времени, а предложений не наблюдается, поделюсь своим видением решения данного вопроса 
(на самом деле, похоже на простенький "хак" и занимает на 5-10 строк больше, чем "чистая" авторизация с Firebase).

А именно, sample Activity, из которого будет видно, что вместо того, чтобы пытаться синхронизировать оба сервиса на некоем высоком уровне,
мы просто посылаем credentials ВК-юзера на сервер Firebase в виде связки email-password, добавляя щепотку соли в виде префикса "vk" (или чего по вкусу) 
в поле password и того же незахешированного префикса, например, в поле email для последующей идентификации провайдера в списке Firebase-юзеров.

*По идее, подобный механизм будет работать в связке с применением любого не-дефолтного по версии Firebase сервиса, который предоставляет собственный механизм аутентификации и, как результат, сессионные данные пользователя.*

Плюс такого решения в том, что в Firebase-password, который нужно передать для успешного использования ВК-креденшлов и который 
лично мне, например, ну совсем не нужен для личных целей, а нужен исключительно для определения identity этого и только этого ВК-юзера, можно запихнуть любую 
информацию по вкусу и которую только можно вытянуть из `VKAccessToken`(в случае данного конкретного провайдера).

Вот как это может выглядеть с использованием ***vk android sdk*** - ведь, как я предполагаю, именно этот инструмент имелся в виду при создании вопроса(код на Kotlin, по запросу могу переписать на Java):

```
class VkontakteSignInActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var isResumed = false

    companion object {
        private val scopeArray = arrayOf(VKScope.EMAIL)
        private val TAG = "VkontakteSignInActivity"
    }

    private lateinit var loginProgressBar: ProgressBar

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in_vkontakte)
        loginProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.login_progress_bar)

        vkontakteLoginButton.setOnClickListener { signIn() }

        VKSdk.wakeUpSession(this, object : VKCallback<VKSdk.LoginState> {
            override fun onResult(res: VKSdk.LoginState) {
                if (isResumed) {
                    when (res) {
                        VKSdk.LoginState.LoggedOut -> {
                            //Теоретически, здесь мы дергаем свою Sign In Button 
                            //и оказываемся в теле функции signIn()
                        }
                        VKSdk.LoginState.LoggedIn -> {}
                        VKSdk.LoginState.Pending -> {}
                        VKSdk.LoginState.Unknown -> {}
                    }
                }
            }
            override fun onError(error: VKError) {
                Log.d(TAG, error.errorMessage)
                Toast.makeText(this@VkontakteSignInActivity, "Session failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }

    private fun signIn(){
        loginProgressBar.show()
        // Вызываем VKSdk.login для дальшейшего onActivityResult(), который нам понадобится
        VKSdk.login(this@VkontakteSignInActivity, *scopeArray)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        val callback = object : VKCallback<VKAccessToken> {
            override fun onResult(res: VKAccessToken) {
                //Собственно, вся "магия" имеет место далее.

                //Здесь может быть любая логика по подготовке нужных
                //креденшлов для последующей отправки на Firebase.
                val authPass = preparePassForAuth(res.userId)

                //Когда данные готовы, получаем instance FirebaseAuth, ведь дальше без него никак,
                //и, собственно, создаем корневой коллбек на регистрацию/аутентификацию 
                //пользовательских данных, которые понадобятся нам для учета.
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                        .fetchProvidersForEmail("vk_${res.email}")
                        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    //Если находим хотя бы одного провайдера с существующими креденшлами,
                    //логиним пользователя. Иначе, регистрируем его в Firebase Auth.
                    if(task.isSuccessful && task.result.providers != null){
                        if (task.result.providers!!.isNotEmpty()){
                            firebaseAuthManager.getAuthInstance()
                            //Не забываем предварительно трансформировать данные в "email-password"
                                    .signInWithEmailAndPassword("vk${res.email}", authPass)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(this@VkontakteSignInActivity) { innerTask ->
                                        processAuthResult(innerTask, authPass) }
                        } else {
                            firebaseAuthManager.getAuthInstance()
                            //Не забываем предварительно трансформировать данные в "email-password"
                                    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword("vk${res.email}", authPass)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(this@VkontakteSignInActivity) { innerTask ->
                                        processAuthResult(innerTask, authPass) } }
                    } else {
                    //На случай unsuccessful response от самого Firebase'овского сервиса
                        Log.w(TAG, "FirebaseAuth:failure", task.exception)
                        Toast.makeText(this@VkontakteSignInActivity,
                                "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }
            override fun onError(error: VKError) {
                loginProgressBar.hide()
                Log.d(TAG, error.errorMessage)
                Toast.makeText(this@VkontakteSignInActivity, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, callback)) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }

    fun processAuthResult(innerTask: Task<AuthResult>, authPass: String) {
    //Обрабатываем внутренний AuthResult'овский коллбек 
    //в зависимости от нужд. Если все ок, делаем свои дела.
        if (innerTask.isSuccessful) {
            vkontakteLoginButton.hide()
            loginProgressBar.hide()
            startActivity(Intent(this@VkontakteSignInActivity, MainActivity::class.java))
        } else {
            //На случай auth failure Firebase'овского сервиса
            Log.w(TAG, "createUpdateUserWithEmail:failure", task.exception)
            Toast.makeText(this@VkontakteSignInActivity, "Authentication failed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    fun preparePassForAuth(userId: String): String {
        //Код для хеширования UID, например
    }

    fun getVKUIdFromPass(hashedPass: String): String {
        //Код для расшифровки UID, например
    }
}
```

***Естественно, для того, чтобы эта связка работала, необходимо включить Способ входа "Адрес электронной почты и пароль" в Firebase Auth - консоли.*** 
После включения я, например, дефолтных поднастроек не менял - все работает, как есть.

**UPD:** добавил немного кода для большей наглядности процессов создания новых, определения уже существующих Firebase'овских аккаунтов и ошибок, которые могут возникать в процессе комплексного запроса.

Comment: У меня такая же идея была, но так любой по uid может зайти, прочитав исходный код. Да, надо еще знать какой email привязан к этому uid. Но все равно лазейка